# How to successfully Restart App Inspection in Android Studio Bumblebee

Tags: android-studio

Im trying this version of Android Studio

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Beta 4
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.7905991, built on November 11, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.0-release-798-AS7442.40)
```

I realise its a Beta release, however Im having difficulty with the App Inspection tool.

Its fine at the start of the day, once I have stopped it and attempt to restart it consistently fails.

Ive tried closing and reopening Android Studio, restarting Android Studio, invalidating cache and restarting Android Studio, clear file system cache and local history and restarting Android Studio

none of these actions can resolve the error state of

```
Could not launch inspector androidx.sqlite.inspection: Inspector with the given id androidx.sqlite.inspection already exists. It was launched by project MyProject
```

Is there an approach I should be taking to resolve this issue?

Comment: Were you able to fix?

Comment: @ZeziReeds no, im currently using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Canary 10
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.9762515, built on March 17, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b653.34-9746777 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.6.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 12
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.images.show.chessboard=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.android.aas (3.5.1)

Answer (score 3):

In my case re-deploying the app fixed it, while restarting Android Studio and explicitly clicking on "stop inspectors" didn't help.

The error message in my Android Studio 2023.1.1 version actually mentioned that that could help:
[image]

> Error was encountered while launching Background Task Inspector. Please redeploy app or restart the inspector by clicking on the link in the notification prompt.